# How do you determine if rsync is setup on a folder?

Tags: rsync

`crontab -l` lists all the `cron` jobs setup for the login. Along similar lines, is it possible to determine if `rsync` has been setup on a folder?

`rsync` help does not list a potential option.

Comment: What do you mean by "_rsync is setup on a folder_"? Are you referring to the `rsync` in daemon/server mode? What's the relevance of `crontab -l` to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync is a command that is run, either manually or programmatically. It is not a feature of a directory (folder).  You could watch the directory for changes (updates to files, removal of files, creation of files), but you'd have to rule out other causes of those actions before deciding it was caused by rsync.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't the program need to maintain the folders it is synching? rsync is executed once and then its manages the sync process until "removed". Is my comprehension incorrect?

Comment: The closest I can think of is when rsync runs as a daemon (with a configuration file); but I imagine most use cases are single command-line calls that synchronize whatever is requested on that command-line.

Comment: @rams Your comprehension is incorrect; `rsync` (at least by itself) does no maintenance at all. When run, it synchronizes any differences it finds *once*, and then exits. In many cases someone does want ongoing synchronization, so they'll write something that runs `rsync` repeatedly (e.g. as a cron job), but this is not built into `rsync` itself.